# id() not working (not completely) in Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

One of my entities has the following declaration for its ID:

```
@Id
private String                  oInstID;
public  String                  getInstID(){return oInstID;}
public void initID(){
    oInstID = OfyController.makeID(Partner.class, null);
}
```

Keep in mind that I have same declaration for my other entities as well.

I have the following testing statements after the ofy.save():

```
Sticky persisted = OfyController.ofy().load().type(Sticky.class).first().now();
String id = persisted.getInstID();
Sticky queried = OfyController.ofy().load().type(Sticky.class).id(id).now();
Sticky queried2 = OfyController.ofy().load().entity(persisted).now();
```

The **persisted** returned the entity

The **id** returned the ID of the entity

The **queried** returned null...which is what my problem is.

The **queried2** returned the same entity as the **persisted**

Any idea why **queried** returned null?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you presenting the entity definition _exactly_? If you have a `@Parent` field, this will cause this behavior. There's nothing obviously wrong with this code, so post a complete example that shows your save operation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My prior experience with Objectify is tiny and very stale, but what you're describing is consistent with [eventual consistency](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency). There's a bit of useful info in [Storing Data with Objectify and Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/using-datastore-objectify).

Comment: @Dave...what does my scenario have to do w/ Eventual Consistency?  Just an FYI...the testing statements above were in written in the JUnit, so EC shouldn't be a factor here.  Thanks!

Comment: EC is a factor if you're using the JUnit against dev_appserver. Dev_appserver simulates eventual consistency for you. That third statement is equivalent to

`SELECT * FROM Sticky WHERE id=?`

which is absolutely subject to EC.

Comment: This is not correct - load().type(t).id(i) is the same as creating a key for {t,i} and performing a get-by-key. It will be strongly consistent. Whatever the issue, it's something else.